# Docker Compose Fastapi query Postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, fastapi

When running docker compose to run a container with Fastapi and another with Postgres, getting an 'exited with code 1' error.  Not sure if the postgres server is choking on the .sql file, or the ports are incorrectly specified to network betweek containers.  All of the file contents are provided to recreate the error.

files are organized like this:

- compose.yaml
- Dockerfile
- requirements
- .env
- app

  - main.py
  - database.py

compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - testNet
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dump-postgres-test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dummy_dump.sql
    networks:
      - testNet
networks:
  testNet:
```

.env

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB="testdb" 
POSTGRES_USER="testuser" 
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="testpassword"
```

requirements.txt

```
fastapi
psycopg2-binary
uvicorn
```

app/main.py

```
from typing import Union
import sys
from fastapi import FastAPI
sys.path.insert(0,'./app')

from app.database import Database

app = FastAPI()
db = Database()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}


@app.get("/users/add")
def add_user(id: int, name: str):
    return db.add_user(id, name)
```

app/database.py

```
import os
import sys
import psycopg2


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        """
        Connect to database and return connection
        """
        print("Connecting to PostgreSQL Database...")
        try:
            # load_dotenv()
            conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host="db",
                dbname="testdb",
                user="testuser",
                password="testpassword",
                port=5432,
            )
        except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
            print(f"Could not connect to Database: {e}")
            sys.exit(1)

        return conn

    def add_user(self, id, firstname):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        SQL = f"INSERT INTO users (id, firstname) VALUES ({id}, {firstname});"
        data = (id, firstname)
        print(data)
        cur.execute(SQL, data)
        self.conn.commit()
```

postgres dump file to load to posgres server: dump-postgres-test.sql

```
-- CREATE SCHEMA testdb AUTHORIZATION "testuser";

CREATE TABLE users (
    uid varchar NULL,
    firstname varchar NULL
);


CREATE TABLE sites (
    sid varchar NULL,
    "location" point NULL
);
```

error:
Connecting to PostgreSQL Database...
Could not connect to Database: connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
exited with code 1

Ideally, I can hit the fastapi server and perform CRUD operations on the postgres server.  I would expect 2 containers to spin up, where I can query the server

`http://0.0.0.0:5000/items/5?q=somequery`

or update the database:

`http://0.0.0.0:5000/user/add/99?firstame=Juan`

Not sure how to best test the postgres server is running correctly, part of the problem of troubleshooting this.

Comment: `host` when connecting to the postgres container should be `db` (i.e. the name of the other container), shouldn't it? `0.0.0.0` usually represents "all interfaces" and isn't really suitable for connecting to a service - at least not when containers are involved

Comment: It worked!  I made the modification in the post.  The psycopg query host is db, as in the compose file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error, but it was due to a different reason and required a modification to `compose.yaml`.
Controlling the order in which containers are started using the `healthcheck` parameter will result in more stable container starts.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - testNet
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dump-postgres-test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dummy_dump.sql
    networks:
      - testNet
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
networks:
  testNet:
```

The "Using Docker Compose" chapter of the following article is a good reference.

- [How to Use the Postgres Docker Official Image | Docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-postgres-docker-official-image/)